# How can solve this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Please how can solve this differential equation?

[image]

$a,b,c,E,h ,A,B$ are constants

Comment: Show us what you have done so far. And some context would be great!

Comment: I try but no way :(

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $y(x)=1/\delta(x)$, you equation is
$$\frac{a-b}hy+\frac{c}{Eh}y^4=2A\left(1+6By\right)y'$$
that rewrites
$$\frac{2Ah(1+6By)}{(a-b)y+\frac cEy^4}y'=1.$$
At this point you need to split the rational expression 
$$\frac{1+6B\,X}{(a-b)X+\frac cE\,X^4}$$ 
into simple elements. (Mathematica does this with the function `Apart`).
The result will depend on the sign of $a-b$. Let us call $\alpha_i$ ($1\leq i\leq3$) the roots of $(a-b)+\frac cEX^3$. We have therefore 
$$(a-b)+\frac cE X^3=\frac cE(X-\alpha_1)(X-\alpha_2)(X-\alpha_3).$$ 
The rational expression can be splitted into
$$\frac{1+6B\,X}{(a-b)X+\frac cE\,X^4}=\frac1{(a-b)X}+
\frac1{a-b}\sum_{i=1}^3
\frac{\beta_i}{X-\alpha_i}$$
where the coefficients $\beta_i$ can be computed by using several techniques described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure).
The differential equation is then 
$$ \frac{y'}{(a-b)y}+\frac1{a-b}\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\beta_iy'}{y-\alpha_i}=1. $$
Integrating both sides we get
$$\frac{1}{a-b}\left(\ln y+\sum_{i=1}^3\beta_i\ln(y-\alpha_i)\right)=x+\mathrm{C^{st}}$$
or in a less pleasant way
$$y(x)\prod_{i=1}^3(y(x)-\alpha_i)^{\beta_i}=K\mathrm e^{(a-b)x}.$$
$K$ is a constant determined by the initial conditions.
From this point, you can replace $y(x)$ by $1/\delta(x)$. Depending on the numerical values of all your coefficients, you will be able to use this expression more or less easily. If these number are, as I suspect, from a problem in mechanics, I wish you good luck.

Comment: thank you so much , can I assume this is analytic solution ?

Comment: You're welcome. The solution is given by an implicit analytic solution. I suppose that whether it is analytic itself will depend on the numerical values of $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I decided to post this as an answer.

Notice that the variables of your equation are separable, so you can write: $$\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\frac{C}{2\theta^2} - 2B \theta - D \theta^2}} = dx, $$ where I have made $\delta \to \theta$ (for not being confused). Now you may integrate both sides of the equation in order to obtain the solution. Since this integral (LHS) is a tricky one, you could use numerical approximation. Is $x$ bounded or restricted in some interval? Cheers

Comment: unfortunately I need analytic solution :(

Comment: Do you have any particular values for $C, B$ and $D$?. Maybe, the radicand could be simplified. If you plug this in Mathematica or WA, you will obtain a very large solution in terms of elliptic integrals. Cheers!

Comment: I try to solve it with Maple I get something cant imagine :((

Comment: I edit the equation , may be this can solve ?